# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {e^{-ax} - e^{-bx}}{x} dx$ using the rule of differentiation under integral sign

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {e^{-ax} - e^{-bx}}{x} dx$ using the rule of differentiation under integral sign.

My Attempt:
Here, $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {e^{-ax} - e^{-bx}}{x} dx$

$a$ and $b$ are parameters.  Considering $b$ as a constant let,
$$F(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {e^{-ax} - e^{-bx}}{x} dx$$
Differentiating both sides with respect to $a$,
$$\frac {dF(a)}{da}=\frac {d}{da} \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac {e^{-ax} - e^{-bx}}{x} dx$$
$$\frac {dF(a)}{da}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {-x\cdot e^{-ax}}{x} dx$$
$$\frac {dF(a)}{da} = \int_{0}^{\infty} -e^{-ax} dx$$
$$\frac {dF(a)}{da} = -\frac {1}{a}$$
So,
$$F(a)=-\log (a) + c$$
How to get the value of $c$?

Comment: It should depend on $b$, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $F(b)=\int_0^\infty 0dx=0$, $F(a)=\ln\frac{b}{a}$, so $c=\ln b$.

Answer (score 1):

Take 
$$I(c)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-cx}-1}{x}dx \implies I'(c)= \int_{0}^{\infty}- e^{-cx}dx=-\frac{1}{c}$$
$$\implies I(c)=-\ln c+k$$
So the given integral 
$$J=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{-ax}-1)-(e^{-bx}-1)}{x} dx= I(a)-I(b)=-\ln a+\ln b=\ln\frac{b}{a}.$$